# sub list without modifying original list in java

Tags: java

Below code actually modifies original list `x`. Is there anyway to sub list the main list considering that modification to sub list should not modify the original list?

```
List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();

x.add(1);
x.add(2);
x.add(3);
x.add(4);
x.add(5);

List<Integer> y = new ArrayList<Integer>();

y.add(1);
y.add(2);
y.add(3);

final List<Integer> z = x.subList(0, 4);

System.out.println("sublist " + z.toString());

z.removeAll(y);

System.out.println("Main list after removing sublist " + x.toString());
```

Result:

```
sublist [1, 2, 3, 4]
Main list after removing sublist [4, 5]
```

Comment: Have you considered creating another list?

Comment: no, i am looping with batch 100 for 10k records,so do want to create new list of sublist.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to use `List<Integer> z = new ArrayList<>(x.subList(0, 4))`

```
   List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    x.add(1);
    x.add(2);
    x.add(3);
    x.add(4);
    x.add(5);

    List<Integer> y = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    y.add(1);
    y.add(2);
    y.add(3);

    final List<Integer> z = new ArrayList<>(x.subList(0, 4));

    System.out.println("sublist " + z.toString());

    z.removeAll(y);

    System.out.println("Main list after removing sublist " + x.toString());
```

**Output:**

```
sublist [1, 2, 3, 4]
Main list after removing sublist [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want the sublist to be a "window" into the original, you need to make a copy, like this:

```
final List<Integer> z = new ArrayList<Integer>(x.subList(0, 4));
```

If you would rather have an unmodifiable list without making a copy, you could use [`Collections.unmodifiableList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29):

```
final List<Integer> z = Collections.unmodifiableList(x.subList(0, 4));
z.removeAll(y); // <<== This will now fail.
```

Comment: The second solution with unmodifiableList is not fit for the question. 
It is still use same reference of the original list.
And if you are using this unmodifiableList in multithreaded application, you will get ConcurrentModificationException if you do get, and other thread is changing the original list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assignment

```
        final List<Integer> z = x.subList(0, 4);
```

will just copy the value of `x` (which is a reference) to `z` as you have not created a new object. They will both refer to the same object. So whatever changes you make in either list, same changes will reflect in the other list as well

This is you should do :-

```
List<Integer> z = new ArrayList<Integer>(//your sublist code);
```

Comment: -1: This is wrong. `z` gets the result of `x.subList(0, 4)` assigned. Its just that `sublist` returns a view on the original list (basically a wrapper object).

Comment: That is what i said that they will refer to the same object. You explained it in a different way, that doesn't mean my answer is wrong.. In first code line `sublist1 will return a view of the original list but in the second line of code where i have allocated new memory for array list `z`, there in braces when i put my `sublist1 then it won't return a view of original list rite. Wow. Thanks for down voting

Comment: `will just copy the value of x (which is a reference) to z as you have not created a new object` thats definitely wrong and something completely different. What you described is equivalent to `z = x`.

Comment: In basic terms, it means that only because you are not allocating new memory for `z`, you are using a reference only of x. The sublist method will still be used when you do `yourlist = new ArrayList<Integer>(//Sublist code here)`. Then also your explanation "sublist returns a view on the original list (basically a wrapper object)" will not be useful here as you have allocated a new memory block

Comment: Im pretty sure that `sublist` creates a new object and thus allocates memory. I cant think of a way it should be solved differently. Edit: See http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html line 913-916, exactly what I have described

Comment: "sublist returns a view on the original list (basically a wrapper object)". "sublist creates a new object and thus allocates memory". Both the things are opposite and you said both of them. If it creates a new object why are the both the list affected when you change any one of them and then y do i have to allocate new memory by using `new1 operator.

Comment: You are really starting to ---- me off, srsly. I have also posted you the relevant snippet. Its called a WRAPPER object. An object which holds a reference to the original list. It is not that complicated -.- . Even if it does not nearly have the memory consumption of the original list it is a different object with different storage. Just execute `z == x` and you will see it will return `false`

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new List using the constructor which copies all the sublist elements in the new List.

```
final List<Integer> z = new ArrayList<>(x.subList(0, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

The sublist is kind of view on the main list. If you ever go into debugging a program using some Collection, you'll find 2 variables i.e. `offset` and `length` defined, for the sublist. Which means there aren't actual physical list. So there isn't anyway to not update the original list by updating the sublist.

You do have to make copy of the sublist to achieve your requirement. As explained in code by others.

From the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29)

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. (If fromIndex and toIndex are equal, the returned list is empty.) The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa. The returned list supports all of the optional list operations supported by this list.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

From Docs:

> A thread-safe variant of ArrayList in which all mutative operations
>   (add, set, and so on) are implemented by making a fresh copy of the
>   underlying array.

or

```
final List<Integer> z = new ArrayList<>(x.subList(0, 4));
```

Comment: where is this method?

Comment: @eswharC which method you are talking about?